# How to use assertThat with any condition?

Tags: kotlin, junit, any, google-truth, assertthat

How can I write the following assertion:

```
org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(result.any { it.name == "Foo" })
```

with Google Truth `assertThat`?

```
com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertThat(result...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that I'm not familiar with Google Truth (hence I don't know if there's an idiomatic way to write it), I would write that assertion like this:

```
Truth.assertThat(result.map { it.name }).contains("foo")
```

or, you can keep the original version:

```
Truth.assertThat(result.any { it.name == "foo" }).isTrue()
```

Playing a bit with it, you could even do:

```
Truth.assertThat(result)
        .comparingElementsUsing(Correspondence.transforming<Foo, String>({ foo -> foo?.name }, "has the same name as"))
        .contains("foo")
```

However, the latter doesn't look very readable, so I'd stick with the first one.

Comment: @ChrisPovirk thanks for updating the answer and fixing the example :-)